# The type HttpStatus does not define isError(HttpStatusCode) defined here in java 17

Tags: java, reactive-programming, http-status-codes, java-17

I am trying to upgrade my existing code to java 17 , but I am getting an error while trying to return the bearer token response. The onStatus method is giving  compilation error but it was working fine in Java 11 . Below is the code

```
Mono<AppResponse> bearer = null;
WebClient cl = WebClient.builder().baseUrl(someUrl).defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/x-www-form-urlencoded").build();
var myUri = cl.post();
var mySpec = myUri.uri(UriBuilder::build);
var keyMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
keyMap.add("client_sc",cl);
............
var oneSpec = mySpec.bodyValue(map);

bearer = oneSpec.retrieve().
          onStatus(HttpStatus::isError,response ->, // The problem is here , i am getting "The type HttpStatus does not define isError(HttpStatusCode) defined here "
          response.bodyToMono(String.class).map(e-> {
          log.error("There is Error ",e);
          thrwo new MyAppException(
          .....
         }))).bodyToMono(AppResponse.class);
   return bearer;
```

The above code was working perfectly in Java 11 , i am not able to understand what is going wrong here.

Comment: Do you have any `.*` imports in your source file? Maybe one of those packages now has a new `HttpStatus` class, so the wrong one is referenced here.

Comment: @JoachimSauer no  i have org.springframework.http.HttpStatus as the import

Comment: Then please reduce your problem to a [mre] that demonstrates the problem and [edit] your question to include that. My only other suspicion is that you somehow pulled in an old version of spring-web (4.x) where the `isError`  method didn't exist. If you ctrl-click `HttpStatus` in your IDE, where does it lead you? Which jar file contains the class it sees?